# why is my Floating Action Button onclick not working?

Tags: android, onclick, floating-action-button

Hi i have a FAB fab_main that has an onclick that enables other FAB's for onclick. now fab_main's onclick works, but the others are not working at all, why? the code is identical, no?

already tried cancelling the hide() for them but that doesn't help...

I might try switching to the support library fab, but if that was the problem fab_main's onclick wouldn't have worked ether, right?

xml:

```
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_button_main"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_button_house"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_button_building"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.FloatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

java:

```
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

FloatingActionButton fab_main = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_main);
        FloatingActionButton fab_house = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_house);
        FloatingActionButton fab_Building = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_building);

//hides fabs
        fab_house.hide();
        fab_Building.hide();

        //defines the main fab onclick
        fab_main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!isFABOpen){
                    showFABMenu();
                }else{
                    closeFABMenu();
                }
            }
        });

fab_house.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                closeFABMenu();
  });
            }
        });

    }

private void showFABMenu(){
        FloatingActionButton fab_main = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_main);
        FloatingActionButton fab_house = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_house);
        FloatingActionButton fab_Building = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_building);
        isFABOpen=true;
        fab_house.setOnClickListener(null);
        fab_Building.setOnClickListener(null);
        fab_house.show();
        fab_Building.show();
        fab_house.animate().translationY(-getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standard_62));
        fab_Building.animate().translationY(-getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.standard_125));
    }

    private void closeFABMenu(){
        FloatingActionButton fab_main = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_main);
        FloatingActionButton fab_house = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_house);
        FloatingActionButton fab_Building = findViewById(R.id.floating_action_button_building);
        isFABOpen=false;
        fab_house.animate().translationY(0);
        fab_Building.animate().translationY(0);
        fab_house.hide();
        fab_Building.hide();
    }
```

EDIT:
My mistake, the fab onclick nulls should have been in the other function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `showFABMenu()`, this line removes the `fab_house`'s `onClickListener()`:

```
fab_house.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Remove this line to fix the problem

The `fab_Building` has no `onClickListener()` defined

Answer (score 2):

You have set fab_house onClick method to null in show fabMenu.. either set it to this and implement override onClick methods or just remove the line

Comment: it would be great if you accept my answer or give upvote